# Openlayers middle mouse button panning

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm pretty new to Openlayers and I have a problem with map panning using middle mouse button. Basically, I want to use the middle mouse button only for map panning, so that when other tools are selected/used (as identify feature tool) the middle mouse won't be used for selecting (only left mouse button).

Any suggestion?

Comment: Which Openlayers version?