# Openlayer pan using only mouse middle button

Tags: mouseevent, openlayers, openlayers-3

I need to build a custom pan for openlayer(ol3) map using press and drag mouse middle key only. This is what i need.

```
new ol.interaction.DragPan({
  condition: function(event) {
     // return event.originalEvent.ctrlKey
    //  need event for mouse middle key instated of ctrl
  }
});
```

Any suggestion?

**NOTE**: similar question is [Openlayers middle mouse button panning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134910/openlayers-middle-mouse-button-panning), with no answer

Comment: `return (event.originalEvent.which == 2)`

Comment: Thanks @Mike, its works just fine